# plotting a linear regression line using point

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, scikit-learn, scipy, linear-regression

i want to plot a regression line by using a (x,y) point.

I did something like this

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.polynomial.polynomial import polyfit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy

# Sample data
x = np.array([4.2])
y = np.array([2.8])
plt.plot(x, y, 'o')
m, b = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
print(m)
print(b)
plt.plot(x, m*x + b)
plt.show()
```

However, it only plot the point not line.Can you please suggest how to plot the line.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems that it plots only one point because you have only one data point. Adding more data points plots the line.

Comment: @Nachiket can you please suggest if i can add 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data contains only one point.  In general, we want to display the fitted curve over the entire x-domain. (Even if here the regression is linear and only requires 2 points).

```
# Display the regression curve
x_dom = np.linspace(0, 5, 200)
y_reg = m * x_dom + b
plt.plot(x_dom, y_reg, c="royalblue", label="Regression curve")
plt.plot(x, y, 'o', c="orange", label="Data")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Note that fitting one point does not make sense. An infinity number of straight lines pass through that point. If you know a second point (such as the origin), the coefficients of the line that passes through these two points can be obtained analytically.

Answer (score 1):

You code works fine, I just added the (0,0) point:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.polynomial.polynomial import polyfit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy

# Sample data
x = np.array([0, 4.2])
y = np.array([0, 2.8])
plt.plot(x, y, 'o')
m, b = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
print(m)
print(b)
plt.plot(x, m*x + b)
```

output:

[image: plot regression]